# FilesSystemWatcher For each item in List, look at that file

Tags: c#, mysql

**Goal:**

The main goal is to get all path names from MySQL, and use File System Watch to watch them paths for rename, deleted and created.

I have this full code here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApp1
   
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Run();
        }

        public static void Run()
        {

            MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("credentials");
            MySqlDataReader myreader = null;
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from files", mcon);
            mcon.Open();

            myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            List<String> list = new List<String>();
            while (myreader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(myreader[1].ToString());

                foreach (string i in list)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
                    watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName($@"{i}");
                    watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName($@"{i}");
                    watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

                    watcher.Created += directoryChange;
                    watcher.Deleted += directoryChange;
                    watcher.Renamed += onRename;

                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
            mcon.Close();


        }   


        private static void directoryChange(object source, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e.ChangeType} - {e.FullPath} - {System.Environment.NewLine}");
        }

        private static void onRename(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{e.OldFullPath} renamed to {e.FullPath}");
        }



    }
}
```

And this is a table in MySQL:

```
ID                   Path
1   G:/Folder/EdGzi/Test purposes Python/file.txt
2   G:/Folder/EdGzi/Test purposes Python/test2.txt
```

**Problem:**

When I run this application. It watches only 1 file(only the top record only from MySQL data). Whereas, it should have been watching all the files returned from MySQL table.

That's why I have created the `foreach` code.

#### Question:

How can I do this?

Comment: Try moving the `foreach` and everything inside it to **after** `mcon.Close();`.

Comment: Maybe it's because `Console.Read`. Are you sure your code don't wait to keyboard input?

Comment: @IanKemp nope, still returns 1 value only.

Comment: may be you miss ``watcher.Changed``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `Console.Read` from the loop, place it after the loop. That will `Console.WriteLine(i);` each record from MySQL table.

Like so:

```
public static void Run()
{
    MySqlConnection mcon = new MySqlConnection("server=WINX-PC04;user id=root;password=GS201706;database=technical");
    MySqlDataReader myreader = null;
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("select * from files", mcon);
    mcon.Open();

    myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<String> list = new List<String>();
    while (myreader.Read())
    {
        list.Add(myreader[1].ToString());
    }
    mcon.Close();

    foreach (string i in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
        watcher.Path = Path.GetDirectoryName($@"{i}");
        watcher.Filter = Path.GetFileName($@"{i}");
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

        watcher.Created += directoryChange;
        watcher.Deleted += directoryChange;
        watcher.Renamed += onRename;     
    }
    Console.Read(); // Likethis
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can given [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8) objects only one directory and file extension.
You must create multiple [FileSystemWatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=netframework-4.8) objects to monitor multiple different files. If you do this, you must c# [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement each event.

This example follows the ***.jpg** extensions, including subdirectories in the target directory.

```cs
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // target main folder
        string directoryName = @"E:\Apps\2019\SADtest\Decupe\SADtest\Veriler\sources\";

        // such as only watch JPG files
        string fileExtension = "*.jpg";


        using (FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher())
        {
            // NotifyFilter is Flag attribute.
            // triggers when file names created, changed or updated.
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.CreationTime | NotifyFilters.LastWrite;
            watcher.Path = directoryName;

            // the Filter propertie must contain wildcards or empty.
            // you cannot write multiple extensions.
            // all files  : *.* 
            // only text  : *.txt 
            // ends withs : *test2.txt
            watcher.Filter = fileExtension;

            // track the same extensions in all subdirectories.
            watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true;

            // register events
            watcher.Created += Watcher_Created;
            watcher.Deleted += Watcher_Deleted;
            watcher.Renamed += Watcher_Renamed;

            // begin watching...
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

            // sample message
            Console.WriteLine("Press 'ENTER' to quit watching.");
            Console.WriteLine($"I am watching the files with the '{fileExtension}' extension in the '{directoryName}' directory.");

            // wait for the user to quit the program.
            Console.WriteLine();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    private static void Watcher_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Renamed:File: {e.OldFullPath} renamed to {e.FullPath}");
    }

    private static void Watcher_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Deleted:File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");
    }

    private static void Watcher_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Created:File: {e.FullPath} {e.ChangeType}");
    }
```

**Here is the console results :**

Press 'ENTER' to quit watching.
I am watching the files with the '*.jpg' extension in the 'E:\Apps\2019\SADtest\Decupe\SADtest\Veriler\sources' directory.

Renamed:File: E:\Apps\2019\SADtest\Decupe\SADtest\Veriler\sources\meee.jpg renamed to E:\Apps\2019\SADtest\Decupe\SADtest\Veriler\sources\sener.jpg
Created:File: E:\Apps\2019\SADtest\Decupe\SADtest\Veriler\sources\logo2.jpg Created
Deleted:File: E:\Apps\2019\SADtest\Decupe\SADtest\Veriler\sources\logo2.jpg Deleted